# (Best practice) Handling multiple simple forms relating to one object in one view

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a working solution but I would like to know if this is the best way to do it.
I have three models: Meal, Indgredient and IngredientWithQuantity (IwQ). Meal can have multiple IwQ and Ingredient can have multiple IwQ.

I created a simple view where you can create Meal (one form), add IwQ (another form) and if needed go to another view to create new Ingredient (yet another form) and then come back to this view where you still will edit the previous Meal.

The only problem is keeping the information about the meal that is being created.
I am doing this through html hidden input field where I store an information about meal_id.

I am simply not sure if this is the best way to exchange this information, because at times it seems a little off.

Could some take a look and tell me if maybe this could be achieved in a more effective manner?
Thanks,

models.py

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    #brand
    #WW


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Meal(models.Model):
    EVALUATION = (
        ('Perfect', 'Perfect'),
        ('Average', 'Average'),
        ('Bad', 'Bad')
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    time_eaten = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=timezone.now, null=True)
    # time_of_day = jaki posiłek?
    bolus_n = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default=0, null=True)
    bolus_s = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    bolus_s_duration = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    interval = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    prev_bolus_n = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    prev_bolus_s = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    prev_bolus_s_duration = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    prev_bolus_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=timezone.now, null=True)
    evalution = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=EVALUATION)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True)

    #recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    

class IngredientWithQuantity(models.Model):
    UNITS = (
        ('g', 'g'),
        ('spoon', 'spoon'),
        ('cup', 'cup'),
        )
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=UNITS, null=True, blank=True)
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        caption = str(self.quantity) + ' ' + str(self.unit) + ' ' + self.ingredient.name 
        return caption
```

views.py:

```
def createMeal2(request):
print(request.POST)
if 'meal_id' not in request.POST or request.POST['meal_id'] == '':
    meal = Meal()
    meal.save()
    meal_id = meal.id

else:
    meal_id = request.POST['meal_id']
    meal = Meal.objects.get(id=meal_id)

if 'meal_form' in request.POST:
    meal_form = MealForm(request.POST, instance=meal)
    if meal_form.is_valid():
        meal_form.save()
    return redirect('/boot/')

iwq = IngredientWithQuantity(meal = meal)
meal_form = MealForm(instance=meal)

if 'ingredient_form' in request.POST:
    ing_form = IngredientForm(request.POST)
    if ing_form.is_valid():
        ing_form.save()
    iwq.ingredient = Ingredient.objects.get(name=request.POST['name'])

if request.method == 'POST' and 'iwq_form' in request.POST:
    iwq_form = IwQForm(request.POST, instance=iwq)
    if iwq_form.is_valid():
        iwq_form.save()

else:
    iwq_form = IwQForm(instance=iwq)

context = {'iwq_form':iwq_form, 'meal':meal, 'meal_id':meal_id, 'meal_form':meal_form}
return render(request, 'meals/create_meal2.html', context)
```

template:

```
{%  extends 'meals/main.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<hr>
<h2>Meal: {{meal.name}}
<hr>

<h2>Ingredients2</h2>
 <form action="/create_ingredient/" method="POST"> 
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type = "hidden" name="meal_id" value={{meal_id}}>
   <input type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add_ingredient" value="Dodaj składnik">
  </form>
<br>
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <table border="1">
    {% for field in iwq_form.visible_fields %}
      <tr>
        <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
        <td>
          {{ field.errors }}
          {{ field }}
          {{ field.help_text }}
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>  
        <input type="submit" value = "Dodaj składnik" name="iwq_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="meal_id" value={{meal.id}}>
 </form>

<h2>Ingredients</h2>
{% for i in meal.ingredientwithquantity_set.all %}
{{i}} <br>
{% endfor %}
<hr>
<form action="." method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{meal_form.as_p}}
  <input type="hidden" name="meal_id" value={{meal.id}}>
  <input type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="meal_form" value="Zapisz posiłek">
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this task I think you can use formtools. It divides the forms into multiple pages and user get to fill them with step by step method. You can skip certain forms depending on answers the user gave beforehand etc. It is very useful and at the end you get the entire data for all the forms. You can also get data for a specific step at a certain point. Here is the link to an article: https://swapps.com/blog/how-to-do-a-wizard-form/
Also here is the documentation link: https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html